# message popup appears on table "has touch"

Tags: asp.net, nexus

I was developing asp.net web application. However, the client reported that now he gots strange message "has touch" when browsing application through table (nexus 10 and chrome and Firefox).

I really have no idea why it is so? 
Please, give me some hints were to look at.
I even do not have table to test this.

I have not found anything in google, except this forum thred: https://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/200143-The-page-at-www-3dbuzz-com-says-has-Touch?p=1593842
It mantiones the same problem, but no description about the source of this message or how to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's coming from jquery.Tablednd.0.7.min.js I think.  Looks like it's been removed in recent versions on github.

https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/pull/6

Good luck.